# How to delete un array in Q--

Tags: arrays, performance

I am getting started to the awesome Q-- language, but I could not find **any reference in the documentation** about how to empty an array without destroying the variable itself.

I came up with :

```
myArray[range[1][100]][iterate[0][myArray[size]][delete[@]]
```

or

```
myArray[range[1][100]][delete[@]]
```

which both work:

```
(myArray[size] = 0) //true
```

It does work but I think there must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQ-- library, as such

```
myArray[range[1][100][$[empty[@]]]
```

Your second solution actually destroys the variable